# If the browser downscales a large image, will it display the same amount of detail on different screen resolutions?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, cross-browser, retina-display

This question relates to web development.

I'm going to start by apologizing for the horrible title but I wasn't sure how to title this. CSS pixels and how they interact with screen resolutions confuse me a bit already, when you add "intermediate pixel layers" and image drawing it's even more nebulous. So here's my actual question:

Let's say that we have an image set to display as `2x1` (css pixels) on a web page. And we instead feed it a `4x1` image (rasterized). The browser will fit this image to the `2x1` css pixels we specified earlier. But, would we technically be able to see all `4x1` pixels on a setup where **1 CSS pixels = 2 device pixels**? Or would it instead resize the `4x1` image to `2x1` then display each pixel twice? And does this change on a per browser/device basis?

Bonus points: How does this play into accessibility tools that zoom into web content for the visually impaired? (if at all).

Comment: Some interpolation takes place to decide which color the pixels take.

Comment: @WaisKamal Thanks for the prompt response! I get that some interpolation will take place when resizing an image. I would like to know if the image is displayed at the "css resolution" or the device resolution (set in the OS).

Comment: You answered that in your question: "The browser will resize this image to fit the 2x1 css pixels".

Comment: @WaisKamal Edited that to make it clearer. I meant that it would fit the image to the 2x1 css pixels. I don't know if it resizes it, that's partly my question.

Comment: Of course it resizes the image. The image looks squeezed.

Comment: @WaisKamal Even if your device resolution is higher? That 2 css pixel image fits inside of 4 screen pixels. So you're saying that it resizes it first then duplicates the first pixel twice on the screen and the second pixel twice on the screen? As a reminder browser css pixels != screen pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. The short answer is **YES** browsers will show different amounts of detail based on screen resolution.

CSS pixels **ARE NOT** screen pixels. If an image is 600x600 pixels and you decide to display it in a CSS-defined area of 300x300 (`img:{width:300px;height:300px}`), it could display as 300x300 screen pixels or it could display as 600x600 screen pixels. Which of the two it is will depend on the end user's OS screen resolution.

**Example**:

I created a 4x1 pixel png image:

[image: 4 by 1 pixel image]

I added this image to an html page and sized it with a `img:{width:2px; height:1px;}`. For good measure, I also added a blue div with `div:{width:2px; height:1px;}` bellow it.

I then set the "css resolution" of the page to half that of my OS screen resolution (If the OS was set to 2000x2000 I made sure that the full html page had a css widthxheight of 1000x1000px). So each css pixel would contain 4 screen pixels.

This is how it displayed:

[image]

Both the image and the blue div are 2px wide (that's css pixels) but they display as 4 screen pixels. In the case of the blue div, it duplicates the pixels to fit the screen resolution. But in the case of the image, it displays all 4 individual pixels. In both cases, it duplicates the pixels vertically to fit the screen resolution (technically it's probably more of a stretch than a duplication, but you get the idea).

I'm not entirely sure about this but I'm assuming at this stage that all browsers act in a similar fashion.